# Spring Transaction Management With Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-transactions

Sorry for my English but great if anyone could help. 
in my case we are in we are inserting 2 rows data . but the problem is that we have insert statement with select max(fileId) from table.

```
Let's Consider i have table: Table1   
id  fileId  name     path    
1    200   file1    /folder  
1    201   file2    /folder1
```

And Insert Query is like

```
Insert into Table1 (fileId,name,path) values((Select max(fileId) from Table1 where name="file2" and path="/folder1" as version)+1,"file2","/folder1");
```

Now the problem is if two transaction executed then entry will be like:

```
id  fileId  name     path 
1    200   file1    /folder
2    201   file2    /folder1
3    202   file2    /folder1
**4    202   file2    /folder1**
```

But it should be like this

```
id  fileId  name     path
1    200   file1    /folder
2    201   file2    /folder1
3    202   file2    /folder1
**4    203   file2    /folder1**
```

we are also using Spring Transaction Management

```
TransactionTemplate temp=new 
TransactionTemplate((PlatformTransactionManager)new 
DataSourceTransactionManager(dsource));

temp.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() { 
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus 
status) {
    //simple insert logic with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
}
});
```

so it is taking max fileId for both inserting row is 201, but it should take 201 and 202 so when doing +1 it should give 202 and 203.

Comment: You'd better use autoincremented column in MySQL or sequence to fetch values for that column in Oracle.

Comment: Yes but here file1 can also have fileId 201,202,203 and file2 can also have 201,202,203 , it basically shows file version so they are not unique.

Comment: If you don't have specific business logic then there should be no difference if file1 has versions 1, 3 and 5 and file2 has versions 2, 4 and 6 instead of 1, 2 and 3. If you need files to have same versions you need to check transaction isolation levels

Comment: Done that also and Oracle support just two isolation level READ COMMITTED and SERIALIZABLE tried wih both but not working :(